# Searching for substring not returning expected result

Tags: python, string, file-io

I'm writing a function that should import a text file and then iterate each line to find lines containing the string "text5". I have written code that looks correct (to me), but I'm not getting the expected result. When I run the program, I'm getting a lot of lines that don't match. However, if I change the input for the find method to just "5" it seems to work properly.

What am I missing here?

```
with open(filename) as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        if 'Text5' in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: what is the input and output you're getting

Comment: I have a large text file where "text5" lives within ~200 lines, when I run this code I'm getting almost the entire file as output rather than just the matching lines.

Comment: What I'm attempting to do is say "iterate each line in the file, and if the line contains 'text5' then print it. "

Comment: `line = file_object.readline()`?

Comment: simply do `[ line for line in open(filename) if 'text5' in line]`

Comment: `str.find()` will return a `-1` when the text is not found, and in Python that's considered a `True` value because it's not zero.

Comment: I added a comparison operator and now I'm getting no lines for output. Looks like martineau's post was correct, but I'm not getting any matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), the `find()` method should be used only if you need to know the position of a sub-string. To check if sub-string is in the line, use the `in` operator.

You should use `if 'text5' in line:` according to the docs and it will work. I think what is happening is even if there is not a match using `find()` it will return -1 and the if statement evaluates that to True.

The only time `find()` will evaluate to False if the sub-string you are searching for is index 0, since it will return the value 0. Any other index value is True.

Comment: I changed the code as per your suggestion and I'm still getting the same result. I think your points were valid, but it looks like something else is the root cause here.

Comment: It must have something to do with my data file then. Try adding this line to your input file and see if it changes your result                                
<Section SectionNumber="0"> <Text Name="Text5"><TextValue>Hostname:   1A</TextValue> </Text> </Section>

Comment: So I created a second data file with only a subset of the original and it worked!! Could it be the case that something in the original data file is stopping the read?

Comment: I don't know what to think. I copied the original data file and saved it as a new text file. After that, the output was corrected. Thank you for your help, I have no clue what could have caused that.